# Join to selects getting two columns from the same field creating two fields with separate conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I join these two select and get the Sum(hr) for each team in that year on one column and Sum(hr) for all teams in that same year on a different column?

```
select  yearID, TeamID, sum(HR) as TeamTHR
from vwPlayersBatting
group by yearID,teamID
order by yearID

select  YearID, sum(hr) as tt
from vwPlayersBatting
group by yearID
order by yearID
```

Comment: Can you give the example of table structure and the expected output according to that?

Comment: Seems as a task for window functions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 Dont have sql server up and running to help more

Comment: I am using SQL server. The tables are all in one view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd use `SUM OVER` to display the year's total along:

```
select
  yearid,
  teamid,
  sum(hr) as teamthr
  sum(sum(hr)) over (partition by yearid) as tt
from vwplayersbatting
group by yearid, teamid
order by yearid, teamid;
```

Example output:

```
yearid | teamid | teamthr | tt
-------+--------+---------+-------
2019   | 1      |      10 |     30
2019   | 2      |      20 |     30
2020   | 1      |      50 |     50
```

If you want this instead:

```
yearid | teamthr (Team 1) | teamthr (Team 2) | tt
-------+------------------+------------------+-------
2019   |               10 |               20 |     30
2020   |               50 |                0 |     50
```

this can't be done with SQL alone. You'd need dynamic SQL (i.e. build your final query from pre-selected data) or use your app/Website to fill a grid in a loop over the SQL results.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is perfect. I will research this to make sure I get it next time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Window Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) like this

```
select  yearID, TeamID, 
    sum(HR) over (partition by yearID,teamID) as TeamTHR,
    sum(HR) over (partition by yearID) as tt
from vwPlayersBatting
order by yearID, TeamID
```